# pyspark Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings cloudera

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

i am conecting to a cloudera server throug ssh connetction

when i run my pyspark code i got that:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.7-1.cdh5.4.7.p0.3/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.7-1.cdh5.4.7.p0.3/jars/avro-tools-1.7.6-cdh5.4.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

the spark version is 1.3.0

i have no accses to the server, so i can't modify pom.xml as everyone said

there is somting else i can do?

than you

Answer (score 1):

This is only a warning from SLF4J logging engine and has no impact to your spark session.

You can get rid of it by modifying `SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH` environment variable. It probably contains result of `hadoop classpath` with `/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.7-1.cdh5.4.7.p0.3/jars/*`. If you replace this wildcard classpath with list of all jars but one (`avro-tools-1.7.6-cdh5.4.7.jar`) the warning will gone.